# Crash Log on Windows Phone 7 device

Tags: error-handling, windows-phone-7

I don't have a WP7 device yet. Everything is functional in My App on a Simulator, but when my customer test it, app does not function at all. e.g. VDO is not playing.

Is there a way to get a crash log from Windows Phone 7? (like iPhone).

Comment: what is "VDO"? Have you not got any error handling in your app to capture the exception details?

Comment: Hi Matt, If i have device with me it should be just put a breakpoint but, I don't have device with me.

Comment: For now, I'm decided to go with self logging based on simple log class at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228723/silverlight-logging-framework-and-or-best-practices

Comment: No sign on 7.1 Mongo to support this importance feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily create your own crash report. Basically this is what you have to do:

- In your App class add an handler for the UnhandledException event
- inside the handler prepare a log with everything you need (stacktrace, memory allocated, etc.)
- use an email composer Task to send the report.

Comment: Thanks Francesco, This is what i think. The self manage log. But if you learn way that iPhone App generate the crash log and send back to developer with zero effort, you will ask same question as me.

Comment: so, far no crash log from OS built-in. so, this is the best answer.

Comment: Sending an email with the crash report is pretty much common practice now.

Comment: You can try using [BugSense](http://www.BugSense.com) - free, with cool analytics supporting WP7, Android, iOS (I am one of the founders)

Answer (score 5):

You can also check [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com) which is a cross-platform(iPhone,Android and Windows Phone) tool that collects and analyzes crash reports from mobile apps.

Disclaimer: I have developed the WP7 plugin.

Comment: If you are affiliated with this product we would like you to disclose this in your answers and in your profile. Thanks.

Comment: I am using vs2010 express for windows phone and therefor cannot install nuget. so I need the zip from https://www.bugsense.com/docs/windowsphone7 but that link is not working.