# how to check log into window phone 7.?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hello I am working windows phone 7 and my application is working perfectly fine into the emulator, but once I start my application into the device it will crashing so how I track the error log into my device.?

how I can check error stack into my device.?

Comment: Exact Dup :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312479/crash-log-on-windows-phone-7-device

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [LittleWatson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx). It allows you to get exception information emailed to you from a real device.
It's easy to modify to add extra logging information if you need it to.